Kardar's Statistical Physics of Fields Chapter 3 Problem 1f
In Mehran Kardar's Statistical Physics of Fields, I'm stuck at the f part of chapter 3 problem 1. The problem is following:
Spin waves: In the XY model of n=2 magnetism, a unit vector $\vec{s}=(s_x, s_y)$ (with $s_x^2 +s_y^2=1$) is placed on each site of a d-dimensional lattice. There is an interaction that tends to keep nearest-neighbors parallel, i.e. a Hamiltonian:
$-\beta H=K\sum_{\langle ij \rangle} \vec{s_i} \cdot \vec{s_j}$
The notation $\langle ij \rangle$ is conventionally used to indicate summing over all nearest neighbor pairs $(i, j)$.
On part f, we have the following question:
(f) Find an expression for $\langle \vec{s_0} \cdot \vec{s_x} \rangle = \Re \langle \exp[i\theta_x - i\theta_0] \rangle $ by adding contributions from different Fourier modes. Convince yourself that for $|x| \rightarrow \infty $ only $q \rightarrow 0$ modes contribute appreciably to expression and hence calculate the asymptotic limit.
$\theta$ here refers to the angles between spins and $q$ refers to the Fourier representation $\theta(x) = L^{d/2} \sum_q \tilde\theta(q) e^{i \vec{q} \cdot \vec{x}}$ where $L$ is the length of one side of a $d$ dimensional lattice cube with periodic boundary conditions.
Note that the full question and a solution can be found in here as well: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-334-statistical-mechanics-ii-statistical-physics-of-fields-spring-2014/fcd5f9627c42dae60ef4da89c410b7b0_MIT8_334S14_TestReview_Sol1.pdf (problem 8).
I can't understand the solution though. Specifically, in the solution I posted in the link, I can't wrap my head around the part where the author argues about completing the square and the solution immediately following that. I would appeciate any help.
